# Separate logins with different privileges using switch case in php 5.5

Tags: mysqli, switch-statement, php-5.5

I'm having some trouble with a block of code I'm trying to implement.
My thought process was to have different users with different attributes in the "userType" (which is an INT type) column in my database and to have a switch case to take the result of the query and select which page to redirect to. The links for re-direction haven't been inserted yet as the login switch case isn't working.

Here is the code for my "loginsuccess.php"

```
<?php
session_start(); // Right at the top of your script
?>

<?php 

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="google_test"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="google_test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

  if($_SESSION['$myusername']==true)
    { 
        $sessionUsername = $_SESSION['$myusername'];
        $userType = "SELECT userType FROM '$tbl_name' WHERE username='$sessionUsername'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $userType);

        switch ($result){
            case "1":
                //userType 1 is admin
                echo $_SESSION['$myusername'];
                echo ", Login Successful. Welcome Admin.";
                break;
            case "2":
                //userType 2 is business
                echo $_SESSION['$myusername'];
                echo ", Login Successful. Welcome to your business page.";
                break;
            case "3":
                //userType 3 is general user
                echo $_SESSION['$myusername'];
                echo ", Login Successful. Welcome to the Fun Finder App!!.";
                break;
            default:
                echo $_SESSION['$myusername'];
                echo ", it appears that your user type has not been defined yet.";
                echo " Please contact support to resolve this issue.";
        }
}
  elseif($_SESSION['$myusername']==false)
    {
        echo "oops......";
      //echo '<a href="register.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
    }
    ob_end_flush();
  ?>
```

My login script is working and passes the username and password through the database successfully via another php page. The result I'm getting from this php file is that the switch case goes directly to the default case regardless of which login I use. I'm assuming it is something to do with my query not returning the proper result as I tried to echo the $result variable and got nothing. Php is not my strongest language so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli_query returns a result object and not the actual value. You can read the value from that object however:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

As an additional hint: it might make sense to store these user privileges along with the user login name in the session once the user succesfully authenticates. (There might be more places where this info is needed - that way you don't need to do queries all the time)
The only drawback is that this will not respond to permission chamgesnfor that user (when a user becomes admin he will need to login again)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I must have read right over that part.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you must use  `mysql_fetch_array()` to store the result from the database before using it in a switch case.

example:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$privilege=$row['usertype'];    //user type is from the column in your table
```